# After deploying docker image to civo it still says 404 page not found

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes

Following are the components for my NodeJS application which is kept at some dockerhub/registry.

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: just-speak-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: just-speak
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: just-speak
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: just-speak
        image: "codingnightmare/just-speak:v1"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
```

**service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: just-speak-service
  labels:
    app: node-app
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "just-speak"
      port: 3000
  selector:
    app: just-speak
```

**ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
  labels:
    app: just-speak
  name: just-speak-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: just-speak.<my cluster name>.k8s.civo.com
      http:
        paths:
          -
            backend:
              service:
                name: just-speak
                port:
                  number: 3000
            path: /
            pathType: "Prefix"
```

I have pasted my config file to `~/.kube/config` when I run the command

```
kubectl cluster-info
```

then the output is alright

```
CoreDNS is running at <correct address>
Metrics-server is running at <correct address>

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
```

But when I try to list all the running clusters with `civo kubernetes list` then the result remain empty. I had ran the **apply command** to all 3 files like

```
kubectl apply -f <all 3 files>
```

This command also ran successfully and created deployment. But still when I try to access the application on the link specified in **ingress.yaml** it shows

```
404 page not found
```

I have tried to forward the pod with localhost port 3000 then it worked but I want to deploy it on civo using my `ingress` file.
I ran this command :

```
kubectl port-forward <pod-name> 3000:3000
```

When I've open API endpoint from civo dashboard then it shows a JSON file

```
{
"kind": "Status",
"apiVersion": "v1",
"metadata": {},
"status": "Failure",
"message": "Unauthorized",
"reason": "Unauthorized",
"code": 401
}
```

is this the error? if yes then how to authorize it? I've already set my civo API key.

Comment: Does the server have a logfile that you can check to see what the requested URL was?

Comment: which server/logfile are you taking about, the config one?

Comment: The web server's log file. Where you see the IP address, request, and so on.

Comment: This is the link `just-speak.7fe18cde-3f87-441e-afd7-0d531995ed3d.k8s.civo.com` and when I forwarded the port to 3000 using `kubectl port-forward <pod-name> 3000:3000` then it's working good. I don't know why it's not being deployed on civo then.